# How to say if a Matrix is singular or non-singular

Tags: linear-algebra

I have this question, as I used the method of determinants to prove that this matrix was singular (it is not), and I was told that it wasn't about proving it, but establishing it.

I am very confused. How could then one say if a Matrix is singular or not? (this one is not, but how do I establish it?)

This is the matrix in question:

$A=\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 2 &-3 \\ 
 -1&  2& 3\\ 
 0& 1 & 1 
\end{pmatrix}$

Any help would be very welcomed. And many kind wishes.

Comment: A (square) matrix is indeed singular if and only if its determinant is zero, but there are also lots of other equivalent conditions. I think you are not likely to get a useful answer here without detailing exactly what it is you were asked to do.

Comment: I don't think the matrix you give is singular. If you add the top row to the second row, you get three rows that are clearly linearly independent.

Comment: @MikeF Thank you, I made the proof through the determinants and got that it wasn't a singular matrix. But then I was told that I wasn't supposed to prove it. So that's why I am very confused. In spanish the word the problem has is: "Determinar" (to establish), so it's about "Establish if the matrix is singular or not". I don't really know what to do, and I am very confused.

Comment: Thank you, @JaapScherphuis It is indeed not singular. I proved it with the determinant method, but I was told I was not supposed to prove it, but to establish if it is singular or not. I have no idea what to do, so that's why I am quite confused and lost.

Comment: @MonicaP it seems like this is more a question about an unclear homework problem. I recommend asking your professor the difference between "prove" and "establish" in this case.

Comment: @roundsquare I did, but I get no answer. It's not a conventional school. It's more self-studying, and the teachers are just there to grade. They don't teach anything at all, we have to learn everything by ourselves.. And though I sent a message some days ago, I have gotten no answer and today is my last day to solve this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'll preface this by saying that I'm not certain regarding exactly what you are asking.

As was noted in the comments the answer will depend on what definition of singular you are using. It is the case that a matrix $A$ is singular if and only if $\det A = 0$. You can easily see that $A$ is not singular by computing
$$\det A = \det\begin{pmatrix} 2 & 3\\1 & 1 \end{pmatrix} - 2\det\begin{pmatrix} -1 & 3\\0 & 1 \end{pmatrix} - 3\det\begin{pmatrix} -1 & 2\\0 & 1 \end{pmatrix} = -1 + 2 + 3 = 4 \neq 0.$$
However, depending upon the definition of singularity you're using, you may need to prove that $\det A = 0$ is equivalent to $A$ being singular.

Comment: Thank you, @GaryMoon. This is what I did, I got this same result using the determinant method, so I got that my system was not singular, but I was told it was not about proving it, but "establishing" if the matrix was singular or not. I honestly don't know what to do then. I am very confused.

Perhaps it's what you say at the end, about proving that det A=0 is equivalent to A being singular...

Comment: @MonicaP I'm not sure what the comment about "proving" versus "establishing" is about. When talking or writing math, I would consider these to be synonymous. Perhaps what this person was getting at was that you didn't need to "write a proof", but that you merely needed to do a computation to "establish" that the matrix is singular. However, I can't know that. In your course, what definition of singular do you use? Have you covered a theorem concerning equivalent formulations of singularity?

Comment: No, sorry, @GaryMoon . This is more like a self-learning course. The person who is like the professor is just there to grade. So they don't teach us anything, we have to look for everything by ourselves. I think if you feel confused too, then perhaps I am not so wrong at feeling lost about it. Although I have asked for clarification to my tutor, I get no answer. I might just leave it like that, it some points off. As for me, I said in my work that  the determinant was different from 0, so it didn't have an inverse, and it meant it was not singular. But it seems I have to do something else.

Comment: @MonicaP I see. Given the comment about "establishing" as opposed to "proving", I would imagine that computing the determinant would suffice. You could check your textbook to see the definition of singular and what theorems you have at this point, if you wanted to be careful. Also, note that A actually does have an inverse. A matrix A has an inverse if and only if it is not singular (if and only if its determinant is non-zero).

Comment: Thank you so much, @GaryMoon . I shall then try to do that. I will put your answer as the correct one for all this help from you. Thank you for helping us, who can feel quite lost in some concepts and things.